# How? from an Int can I get the Upper Char value?

Tags: java, type-conversion, decorator

I have a java question that I'm a bit confused about. 
Been searching around and testing some stuff but without any success.

I have this FilterWriter class that have to change my string, char and int to it's upper value.

```
 public class UpperCaseFilterWriter extends FilterWriter {

 public UpperCaseFilterWriter(Writer wrappedWriter) {
    super(wrappedWriter);
 }

 @Override
 public void write(String str, int off, int len) throws IOException {
   while(len-- > 0){
     write(str.charAt(off++));
   }
 }

 @Override
 public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
   while(len-- > 0){
     write(cbuf[off++]);
   }
 }

 @Override
 public void write(int c) throws IOException {
   //TODO Change int c to upper int c
   out.write(c);
 }
}
```

For now my `write(String) method` and my `write(char[]) method` are calling my `write(int c) method`.

But now I need to

1. Take my int c
2. Convert it to a char
3. Change the char (if it's a letter) to it's Upper value
4. Transform it again to an Int to pass it to my method write(int c)

It's in UTF-8 encoding so I have "é" or "ä" kind of letters.

I've already tried to do int -> char -> upper char -> int in different ways but it wasn't a success.

If somebody can help my with this or give me info where to look at, it would be great. Maybe I need to do it the other way or maybe there's a way of doing it with some byte encode/decode... I don't know.

Thanks!!

Comment: `out.write(Character.toUpperCase((char) c));` ?

Comment: No, not the UTF-8 encoding. `char`, `String` and, in this case, `int` are for a UTF-16 code unit. Both of those encodings are for the Unicode character set. So, you have Unicode characters. Perhaps you mean the eventual output encoding is to be UTF-8. That doesn't have any bearing on the arguments.

Comment: For uppercase, which locale would you apply?

Answer (score 1):

`Character.toUpperCase` is what you need: it can directly convert code points:

```
 @Override
 public void write(int c) throws IOException {
   //TODO Change int c to upper int c
   out.write(Character.toUpperCase(c));
 }
```

It correctly processes non ascii characters and for instance successfully converts `é` to `É`